# Hibernate conditionally subCriteria

Tags: hibernate, conditional-statements, subquery, criteria-api

i need to convert this HQL:

```
FROM Appointment a WHERE (a.group==null OR :user MEMBER OF a.group.groupMembers)
```

to criteria. How can i archieve that a subcriteria is only used when a maincriteria is not matching?

i tried something like that, but i'm stuck:

```
Criteria subcrit = crit.createCriteria("group");
subcrit.createAlias("groupMembers", "gmembers");
crit.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("group", null), Restrictions.eq("gmembers.snuserId", user.getId())));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok i found a soulution for me:
first i created a detached criteria, which finds all group ids where the user is member:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Group.class);
subquery.createAlias("groupMembers", "gm");
subquery.add(Restrictions.eq("gm.userId", user.getId()));
subquery.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
```

Then for my main criteria:

```
    crit.add(
            Restrictions.or(
                    Restrictions.isNull("group"),
                    Subqueries.propertyIn("group.groupId", subquery)
                    )
            );
```

Hope it helps someone